# NormallScroll and fitToSection

Tags: fullpage.js

I have two sections. Second section has very big height, so i marked it as "normalScrollElements". And i would like to have fullpage.js appearence between this two sections and having default browser scrollbar. Disabling fitToSection made it close, but only default browser scroll is working :(

```
        $('.scroll-sections-wrap').fullpage({
        sectionSelector: '.scroll-section',
        scrollBar: true,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        css3: true,
        easingcss3: 'ease-in-out',
        scrollingSpeed: 900,
        fitToSectionDelay: 500,
        responsiveHeight:650,
        responsiveWidth:1000,
        fitToSection:false,
        normalScrollElements: '#second-section-id',
        verticalCentered:false,
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Second section has very big height, so i marked it as "normalScrollElements".

That's not the way you are suppose to use `normalScrollElements`. Normal scroll elements is for small elements that needs to use their own scroll.

> **normalScrollElements:** (default null) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements. (For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2')

You should be using `scrollOverflow:true`:

> **scrollOverflow:** (default false) defines whether or not to create a scroll for the section in case its content is bigger than the height of it. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin. Consider using delegation or load your other scripts in the afterRender callback. In case of setting it to true, it requires the vendor plugin jquery.slimscroll.min and it should be loaded before the fullPage.js plugin.

Comment: But this make inner scrollbar, however i wan't to use default body scroll.

Comment: fullpage.js doesn't provide a way to do what you want. You will have to do it by yourself then. Detecting when you reach the bottom or top of your scrollable element and then calling the moveSectionUp or moveSectionDown functions of fullpage.js.

Comment: Thanks for so fast support. I think I'll do that.